# What conditional statement is the following?

Tags: grammar

I was reading an AP report and I came up at the following passage:

> If the NATO troops **do** pull back, it **would** leave vast areas of the country unprotected including border areas with Pakistan. It **would** essentially mean the end of the strategy of trying to win hearts and minds by working with and protecting the local populations.

Shouldn't this be 'did' at the first place?

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/316123/2085).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possibilities, summed up by *did-would* and *do-will*; not *do-would* (except for colloquial/informal cases where *do* means essentially the same thing as *did*).

If it was meant to be *did-would*, *were to* is a more commonly acclaimed phrase (making this a [future subjunctive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Future_subjunctive) construction):

> If the NATO troops **were to** pull back, it **would** leave vast areas of the country unprotected including border areas with Pakistan.

*Did* (or Past Simple) can be simply another way to express the subjunctive (replacing *were to*):

> If the NATO troops **did** pull back, it **would** leave vast areas of the country unprotected including border areas with Pakistan.

If it was meant to be *do-will*, then it's a [factual conditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence#Factual) construction:

> If the NATO troops **do** pull back, it **will** leave vast areas of the country unprotected including border areas with Pakistan.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence#English) has some examples of proper usage, demonstrating both factual future conditional and future subjunctive:

> If + Present Simple/Present Progressive + Present Simple/Present Progressive/Future Simple/Future Progressive/Imperative
>
> - *If + I miss the bus, + I will be late for school*
>
> If + Present Perfect/Present Perfect Progressive/Preterite/Past Continuous + Full Infinitive + Conditional Present/Conditional Present Progressive:
>
> - *If + I was + to miss the bus, + I would be late for school.*
>
> In some dialects: If + Imperfect Subjunctive + Full Infinitive + Conditional Present/Conditional Present Progressive
>
> - *If + I were + to miss the bus, + I would be late for school.*
>
> In some dialects: If + modal auxiliary "should" + Bare Infinitive + Conditional Present/Conditional Present Progressive
>
> - *If + I should + miss the bus, + I would be late for school.*

Comment: *If we do get ice cream later tonight, it would leave our piggy bank empty; it would mean we can't get ice cream tomorrow* sounds fine to me in normal speech. I understand your point, but I think I use *did* for something hypothetical and *do* for something that may well happen, without regard for the statement that follows. If other speakers do so as well, that explains the phenomenon. It's also not clear if OP's excerpt is part of a quote/reported speech.

Comment: @aediaλ- it's not a quote nor a reported speech.

Comment: I just knew there had to be a downvote somewhere.  What is it this time?

Comment: If NATO **do** downvote, it **would** be better if they left a comment.

Comment: The "it would mean we can't get ice cream tomorrow" isn't quite right to me.  "it would mean we *couldn't* get ice cream tomorrow" is the preferred construction.