# Is the second conditional more polite than the first?

Tags: conditionals, first-conditional

I have learnt that the difference between the first and second conditionals is a possibility: the former implies higher likelihood than the latter.

However, in spoken English, I hear the second conditional sentence more often, as in the following pair.

> 1. If I am offered the job, when will I start?
> 2. If I was offered the job, when would I start?

Does 2 sound more natural/polite? If so, is it because of the odds?

Comment: Yes, I think the first conditional (as it's termed) comes across as being more direct than the second conditional. *Politeness* is often associated with being less direct than absolutely necessary, so the second form *can* come across as more polite. Whether it is more *natural* depends a lot more on local factors. Some societies value directness; others shy from it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally got it, I feel like it's very similar to express the politeness across countries :)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped. :)

Comment: You might look at the article [Native speakers and the use of conditional statements](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79092/native-speakers-and-the-use-of-conditional-statements?rq=1).